# How to make an aspect detect a method with multiple annotations

Tags: spring-aop, spring-aspects

I have a spring application and I want to use aspects to perform some performance logging.

I want to only log methods annotated with @Measured, so I created an annotation as follows :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Measured {
    boolean logParameters() default true;
    boolean logResponse() default true;
    boolean measureTime() default true;
}
```

The aspect is as follows:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MeasuredAspect {

    @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(com.waelawada.web.Measured)")
    public void isMeasurableEvent(){

    }

    @Around(value = "isMeasurableEvent() && @annotation(measured)")
    public void addEventToMDC(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Measured measured) throws Throwable{

        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs());
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(measured.measureTime()){
            MDC.put(methodName,endTime-startTime);
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine for a method like

```
@Measured
    public boolean getUser() {
}
```

Now I want to annotate a spring mvc controller method that is already annotated with @RequestMapping, but the apsect doesn't seem to detect it.

```
@Measured
    @RequestMapping(value = "/activity", method = GET)
    public final String userProfile(@ModelAttribute(USER) User user,
                                     Model model) {
//Do Something
}
```

How can i make the aspect detect this method? I am using spring aop definded in the context xml file as `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false"/>`

Comment: please post your relevant config files.